# How to determine vocal range required to sing a particular song from sheet music

Tags: sheet-music, vocal-range

I need to list the required vocal ranges for a number of songs in order to find singers to perform in a show. Is there a way I can easily determine this from the sheet music? Thanks so much in advance :-)

Answer (score 4):

The range (lowest to highest note) alone doesn't necessarily tell you the ideal vocal type for the song and key. You get help for that from the song's *tessitura,* or *the range within which most of the notes fall*.

A mezzo soprano might be comfortable with a phrase or two going up to, say, an A below high C, but if the song  has a lots of high notes, it may be better suited for a soprano, or might need to be transposed down to be comfortable for a mezzo, who might otherwise say something like "I can sing all the notes, but *it lies too high for my voice*." You could think of the tessitura as  a song's "center of gravity" in terms of pitch.

Answer (score 3):

You look at the sheet music and find the lowest note and highest note for each voice in a song. That's the range for that song

Comment: I believe the question is not asking for the range of notes but for the kind of voice (soprano, mezzo soprano, tenor, baritone, etc.).  Two songs can have an identical range of notes but be suited to different kinds of voices.

Comment: @phoog The question specifically asks about the **vocal range** and not the type of voice.

Answer (score 1):

One simply searches the part of the sheet music that one wishes to sing, then determines what the closest written note to the bottom of the paper is, then the highest for the top. Subtract the two to find the required range.

(You should be able to read the notes for this to work, obviously. Be careful of accidentals- C♭ to E♯ is a tritone when you hear it)

Also, if you don't feel confident with working with intervals, you can convert them all into half-steps and then put the difference as the range.